# bus error assistance

Tags: c

I have a visual program that uses ncurses to display text for a setup program, it seems works fine on gcc 2.9.5 (don't ask) but on newer gcc it crashes.

```
char   *
dofDisplay(dlistptr *ptr)
{
        static char p[100];

        sprintf(p, " %-36s ", (*ptr)->datainfo.option);
        return p;
}
```

GDB reports the following:

```
0x0000000000402811 in dofDisplay (ptr=Variable "ptr" is not available.
) at file.c:676
676             sprintf(p, " %-36s ", (*ptr)->datainfo.option);
```

dlistptr is a struct that is defined in another file.

Comment: Code looks ok - it might be in the calling routine

Comment: Can you show what is dlistptr in both declaration and definition please?

Comment: So, what exactly does GDB report? You provided two lines that show where it happened, but not the actual report.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries compiled by different compilers (or different versions of the same compiler) might use different calling conventions and thus not have binary compatibility.  You might consider remaking the whole project with the new compiler if you haven't already to see if that fixes it.

Comment: This code is 14 years old; I was trying to see if it would work on newer systems. This seems to be the only showstopper as far as I can tell. What would you suggest as trying to isolate the issue? gdb isn't providing useful information.

Comment: Start by getting rid of that weird double dereference and recompiling.

Comment: Hmm, going by the name, `dlistptr` should be a pointer to a `dlist`, so the double dereference could be okay.

Comment: This appears to be an issue on 64bit systems. The code works fine on 32bit.

Comment: @DanielFischer: suppose that would make sense.